# Ionic Android "the redirect_uri is not supported" Facebook

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, satellizer

I am new in this of authentication with social networks, but I am developing an application with Ionic, Node, Mongo and Satellizer https://github.com/sahat/satellizer to make the auth with facebook and It's working fine on the browser but when I test it on android emulator I get this error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vlNJIDJA6RTHlpeml5YjFxNUU/view?usp=sharing

**My local configuration:**

```
    // Satellizer configuration
   // Configuration common for all providers.
  var commonConfig = {
    // Popup should expand to full screen with no location bar/toolbar.
    popupOptions: {
      location: 'no',
      toolbar: 'no',
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: window.screen.height
    },
  };

    // Change the platform and redirectUri only if we're on mobile
  // so that development on browser can still work. 
  if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    commonConfig.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000';
  }

  api = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/";
  //api = "https://testing-miguelcrespo.c9.io/";
  $authProvider.loginUrl = api+'auth/login';
  $authProvider.signupRedirect = '/';


  $authProvider.facebook({
    clientId: '1553815514880424',
    url: api+"auth/facebook"
  });
```

**My facebook app details:**
**APP ID:** 1553815514880424
**Site URL:** http://localhost:3000/
**App Domains:** localhost

Comment: sorry, but did you solve the problem? I am facing the same situation here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a web client and Google giving the same response. Will it work for you if you go for implicit flow. Try:

```
      $authProvider.google({
        clientId: '1553815514880424',
        url: api+"auth/facebook",
        responseType: 'token'
  });
```